# Meteor Cordova: Cannot get camera plugin to work, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined

Tags: cordova, meteor, camera

I am trying out the Meteor Cordova camera plugin and it won't work, and I have no idea what I'm missing.

Here is what I did:

1. Meteor create new project
2. Added the cordova camera package `meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.camera@0.3.1`
3. Programmed the default button on screen to take a picture and then append it to the body.
   This should use the camera built into the laptop computer but all I get when I click the button is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined`

   And when I run the app in the iPhone simulator with the command `meteor run ios` and click the button I get a popup error: `Failed because: no camera available`

This is what my html and js file look like:

**main.html**:

```html
<head>
  <title>cameraTest</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
```

**main.js**:

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0

  function onSuccess(imageData) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      $('body').append(image);
  }

  function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
  }

  Session.setDefault("counter", 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get("counter");
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {

      navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `mdg:camera` package? https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:camera

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do. The meteor cordova wiki is really confusing and makes no mention of the camera package. I was under the impression I needed to add the camera package through cordova.

Comment: Where on the web is there documentation the covers meteor mobile? I thought the meteor mobile plugins would be listed here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration, but I didn't find em, I had to do some searching to find the plugins. So I guess I am wondering if there is another place with documentation that covers meteor mobile and supported plugins.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Every Cordova plugin that works with Cordova should work with Meteor too. If you don't know how to use the plugin, refer to Cordova docs.

Comment: Huh, that is exactly why I made this stackoverflow question is because I did refer to the docs. And the docs says to use the camera plugin use the command 'meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.camera@0.3.1'. I did that and it didn't work, hence I made this post. Then I noticed I needed to use Meteor specific mobile packages which worked. So can you please help me understand why this is?

Comment: no idea why your code doesn't work. You can look at the source of code of the camera package. It uses the same plugin.

Comment: @imslavko mdg:camera package won't work with meteor version 2.0, it shows an error related to less package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because cordova code must be included into a closure, as said on [documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#adding-cordovaphonegap-specific-javascript-code-to-your-application). You have to do this in your `events` functions. See bottom.

PS: you can not test camera on iOS emulator, use a real iPhone instead.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    // The correct way
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success));
});

// Will not work
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success));
```

Your code will become:

```
Template.hello.events({
  'click button': function () {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried as suggested, but still doesnt work. 
Meteor.startup(function () {
   navigator.camera.getPicture(console.warn, console.error, { quality: 50,
 destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
   });
});