# Meteor Cordova: navigator.camera is undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I am trying to make this work. I installed cordova-plugin-camera like it stands in the documentation.

`meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-camera@2.2.0`

Then I was trying to log navigator.camera it was undefined. After digging I found this on this site:

```
Template.round.onCreated(function(){
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log(navigator.camera);
  });
});
```

Still no luck. Does anyboday have a quick checklist or an idea what is wrong?
I am testing in my Browser. The git says it should work.

Comment: Could you share the tutorial or the site you used

Comment: I have looked at the documentation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454473/meteor-cordova-cannot-get-camera-plugin-to-work-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-rea) and at this post on this site regarding my  problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454473/meteor-cordova-cannot-get-camera-plugin-to-work-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-rea). As mentioned the solution above does not work for me.