# Meteor navigator.camera.getPicture not found

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the `cordova-plugin-camera@4.0.3` but i keep getting:

```
"Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined".
```

I already have the Meteor.startup function in my main.js.
I don't understand why it's not working.

```
uploadPicture() {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(this.success, this.failure,_.extend(options, {
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
  }));
}
```

I am trying to run this function when clicking on the take a picture button. But that is when i get the error. I am currently testing on my computer not yet on a device.

I also noticed that my navigator doesn't find the .camera.

If anyone can help me out it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221549/meteor-cordova-navigator-camera-is-undefined